# How can I use let statement to get combinations for subset sum in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
let rectangles = 
       [(a,b,c,d) | d <- [1..10],c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10],a+b+c+d == 22]
```

I have this code that works but I want to make this a function so I can change the value of 22

Comment: these won't give you rectangles but 4-sided polygons (quadrilateral).  Also you'll get all the permutations of the 4 sides as separate shapes.  Perhaps define it as a <= b <= c <= d.  Note also that some will be invalid as shapes e.g. (1,1,1,19)

Answer (score 2):

Just add an argument name after `rectangles` and use that in place of 22. Example:

```
let rectangles perimeter = [(a,b,c,d) | d <- [1..10],c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <-[1..10],
    a+b+c+d == perimeter]
```

---

Optional Information

---

If you're curious, you can write a function Haskell in a few ways, but only some of them apply in each context.

To define a global function, you omit the let (and make sure that the line(s) is/are unindented and not a part of any other definition).

```
 rectangles perimeter = [(a,b,c,d) | d <- [1..10],c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10],
            perimeter == a+b+c+d]
```

Within a definition, the syntax is the same but surrounded with `let` .. `in`.

```
squares = let
              sidelengths ceil = [1..ceil]
          in
              [ (a,a,a,a) | a <- sidelengths 10 ]
```

If you don't like `in`, you can use `let` within `do`:

```
    squares = do
                  let sidelengths ceil = [1..ceil]
                  [ (a,a,a,a) | a <- sidelengths 10 ]
```

At last, in every instance, you could also move the argument name to the right of the equals sign if you surround it with `\` and `->`.

```
let rectangles = \perimeter->
    [(a,b,c,d) | d <- [1..10],c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <-[1..10],
       a+b+c+d == perimeter]
```